# customizing google map tile server url

Tags: google-maps

I use this url for fetching map tile from google server

```
http://mts0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@189000000&hl=en&src=app&x=41189&y=25680&z=16&s=Gal
```

I wonder if there is a way to customize this url, by adding some extra parameters to fetch tile without any label of streets or extra info or overlays.
something just like customizing map in map api v3.
any suggestion would be welcomed.

Comment: You can not use the [Static Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)..?

Comment: I want to use it in an android application with static map you don't have much control for caching and ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I didn't find a documentation about it, but there is a parameter `apistyle`

the value(must be urlencoded) to hide street-labels would be

```
s.t:3|s.e:l|p.v:off
```

The following is a guess because of a missing documentation:

- `s.t` defines the feature-type, the value `3` seems to be  **road**
- `s.e`  defines the element e.g. `l`abels or `g`eometry
- `p` defines the style, `v` stands for `v`isibility , the value `off` should be clear.
  result:

  ```
  https://mts0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@289000001&hl=en&src=app&x=41189&y=25680&z=16&s=Gal&apistyle=s.t%3A3|s.e%3Al|p.v%3Aoff
  ```

[image]

You'll have to play around with the parameters to get the desired result. In the past it was possible to get the style e.g. by inspecting the tile-URL with developer-tools when using for example the [Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) , but they have modified the tile-URLs used by the javascript-API , the parameters now will be encoded somehow.

A list of parameters and values:

### FeatureTypes:`s.t`

- all   `0`
- administrative    `1`
- administrative.country    `17`
- administrative.land_parcel    `21`
- administrative.locality   `19`
- administrative.neighborhood   `20`
- administrative.province   `18`
- landscape     `5`
- landscape.man_made    `81`
- landscape.natural     `82`
- poi   `2`
- poi.attraction    `37`
- poi.business  `33`
- poi.government    `34`
- poi.medical   `36`
- poi.park  `40`
- poi.place_of_worship  `38`
- poi.school    `35`
- poi.sports_complex    `39`
- road  `3`
- road.arterial     `50`
- road.highway  `49`
- road.local    `51`
- transit   `4`
- transit.line  `65`
- transit.station   `66`
- water     `6`

### ElementType: `s.e`

- geometry  `g`
- geometry.fill     `g.f`
- geometry.stroke   `g.s`
- labels    `l`
- labels.icon   `l.i`
- labels.text   `l.t`
- labels.text.fill  `l.t.f`
- labels.text.stroke    `l.t.s`

### Styler:

- color     `p.c`
  **RGBA hex-value `#aarrggbb`**
- gamma     `p.g`
  **float between `0.01` and `10`**
- hue   `p.h`
  **RGB hex-value `#rrggbb`**
- invert_lightness  `p.il`
  **`true`/`false`**
- lightness     `p.l`
  **float between `-100` and `100`**
- saturation    `p.s`
  **float between `-100` and `100`**
- visibility    `p.v`
  **`on`/`simplified`/`off`**
- weight    `p.w`
  **integer >=`0`**

Comment: thank you Dr.Molle .you've been great help.I tried changing the parameters and got what I want.for turning off places and other locations I used s.t:2 and it worked.

Comment: @Mehdi Mousavi: added a list with parameters/values above

Comment: It works fine for me, but do you know what is the syntax for options combination. For example I want to have: apistyle=s.t%3A0|s.e%3Al|p.v%3Aoff   AND   apistyle=s.t%3A6|s.e%3Ag|p.c%3A%23ffb3d1ff  in the same url.

Comment: @Kalitine you separate each set with ',' chracter

Answer (score 9):

Implementation of what Dr. Molle found out:

```
function getEncodedStyles(styles){
var ret = "";
var styleparse_types = {"all":"0","administrative":"1","administrative.country":"17","administrative.land_parcel":"21","administrative.locality":"19","administrative.neighborhood":"20","administrative.province":"18","landscape":"5","landscape.man_made":"81","landscape.natural":"82","poi":"2","poi.attraction":"37","poi.business":"33","poi.government":"34","poi.medical":"36","poi.park":"40","poi.place_of_worship":"38","poi.school":"35","poi.sports_complex":"39","road":"3","road.arterial":"50","road.highway":"49","road.local":"51","transit":"4","transit.line":"65","transit.station":"66","water":"6"};
var styleparse_elements = {"all":"a","geometry":"g","geometry.fill":"g.f","geometry.stroke":"g.s","labels":"l","labels.icon":"l.i","labels.text":"l.t","labels.text.fill":"l.t.f","labels.text.stroke":"l.t.s"};
var styleparse_stylers = {"color":"p.c","gamma":"p.g","hue":"p.h","invert_lightness":"p.il","lightness":"p.l","saturation":"p.s","visibility":"p.v","weight":"p.w"};
for(i=0;i<styles.length;i++){
    if(styles[i].featureType){
        ret += "s.t:"+styleparse_types[styles[i].featureType]+"|";
    }
    if(styles[i].elementType){
        if(!styleparse_elements[styles[i].elementType])
            console.log("style element transcription unkown:"+styles[i].elementType);
        ret += "s.e:"+styleparse_elements[styles[i].elementType]+"|";
    }
    if(styles[i].stylers){
        for(u=0;u<styles[i].stylers.length;u++){
            var keys = [];
            var cstyler = styles[i].stylers[u]
            for(var k in cstyler){
                if(k=="color"){
                    if(cstyler[k].length==7)
                        cstyler[k] = "#ff"+cstyler[k].slice(1);
                    else if(cstyler[k].length!=9)
                        console.log("malformed color:"+cstyler[k]);
                }
                ret += styleparse_stylers[k]+":"+cstyler[k]+"|";
            }
        }
    }
    ret = ret.slice(0,ret.length-1);
    ret += ","
}
return encodeURIComponent(ret.slice(0,ret.length-1));
}
```

Input is in this case a regular google maps styles array - A good wizard for that is [Snazzy Maps](http://snazzymaps.com)

Anyways, thanks to Dr. Molle for saving hours!